# How to identify WordPress language updates?

Tags: language

How can I clearly identify the WordPress language file that triggers the language update notification?

In the current situation I don´t want to auto-update - I tried to manually update the WordPress core language files, but I still have the language update notification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your setting for `WPLANG` (inside 'wp-config.php') defines the language to be used by WordPress, and therefore also the language for which language updates will be checked.

If you want to prevent these language updates from occurring, you can rename the language files under 'wp-content/languages/' to use a non-standard language code, and then modify `WPLANG` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Actually I don´t want to turn of the update notification. I just want to know which language file exactly triggered the notification, as I have to manually update this file :)